# Is it possible to define validations (ranges, lengths) for URI parameters?

Tags: apiblueprint

Is it possible to define validations for a URI parameters?

- (ie, `maxVal`, `minVal`, `maxLength`, etc?)

If not, is there any good workaround for at least documenting a parameter's valid range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated syntax for parameter validation at the moment. The only attributes supported are required/optional and enumeration of possible values.

I would say it is best to use markdown-formatted text to document any further constraints. For example:

```
# Blog Posts [/posts{?limit}]
 ...    

## Retrieve Blog Posts [GET]
Retrieves the list of **ACME Blog** posts.

+ Parameters
    + limit (optional, number) 

        Maximum number of posts to retrieve. The limit **must** be a positive integer.


+ Response 200
```

Dedicated syntax, that will benefit further "machine" processing is planned and will be most likely derived from also planned [MSON](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson) validation syntax.